# Recursive solution to counting the number of ways you can go up a staircase

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow, counting, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to solve the problem of "count ways to reach the nth step in a staircase" with recursion. When given a number of stairs to climb, I have to calculate the number of ways to climb taking either 1 or 2 steps at a time. For example, if there are 4 stairs, we would return 5 since we would have:

```
  * 1 1 1 1
  * 1 1 2
  * 1 2 1
  * 2 1 1
  * 2 2
```

My code is currently throwing a stack overflow exception:

```
 public static int countWaysToClimb(int stairs) {
     return countWaysToClimbHelper(stairs, 0, 0);
 }
 
 public static int countWaysToClimbHelper(int sumNeeded, int currentSum, int possibleCombos) {
     // base - we will reach this base multiple times
     if (sumNeeded == currentSum) {
         possibleCombos++;
         // if we already found a combo, we need to reset the sum
         countWaysToClimbHelper(sumNeeded,0,possibleCombos);  
     }
     
     else if (currentSum > sumNeeded) {
         return 0;
     }
     
     // recurse - add 1 and then add 2
     countWaysToClimbHelper(sumNeeded,currentSum+1,possibleCombos);  
     countWaysToClimbHelper(sumNeeded,currentSum+2,possibleCombos);
     return possibleCombos;             
 }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

- **Base case** (condition that terminates the recursion) is **incorrect**. Every branch of *recursive calls* spawn new branches when it hits the condition `if (sumNeeded == currentSum)` is meat instead of returning the number of combinations. You created an infinite recursion that inevitably leads to a `StackOverflowError`. You have to place a **return** statement inside the curly braces after the first `if` in your code. And comment out the first recursive call (with `0` sum passed as an argument) you'll face the *second problem*: for any input, your code will yield `0`.
- Results returned by *recursive calls* of your method `countWaysToClimbHelper()` are omitted. Variable `possibleCombos` isn't affected by these calls. Each method call allocates its own copy of this variable `possibleCombos` on the **stack** (a memory aria where JVM stores data for each method call), and their values are not related anyhow.
- you actually don't need to pass the number of combinations as a parameter, instead you have *to return it*.

Before moving further, let me recap the basics of recursion.

Every recursive method should contain **two parts**:

- **base case** - that represents a simple edge-case for which the outcome is known in advance. For this problem, there are two edge-cases:

  - `sumNeeded == currentSum` - the return value is `1`, i.e. one combination was found;
  - `sumNeeded > currentSum` - the return value is `0`.
- **recursive case** - a part of a solution where recursive calls a made and when the main logic resides. In your *recursive case* you need to accumulate the value of the number of combination, which will be the **sum** of values returned be two branches of execution: take **1 step** or **2 steps**.

So the fixed code might look like that:

```
public static int countWaysToClimb(int stairs) {
    return countWaysToClimbHelper(stairs, 0);
}

public static int countWaysToClimbHelper(int sumNeeded, int currentSum) {
    // base - we will reach this base multiple times
    if (sumNeeded == currentSum) {
        return 1;
    } else if (currentSum > sumNeeded) {
        return 0;
    }
    // recurse - add 1 and then add 2
    int possibleCombos = 0;
    possibleCombos += countWaysToClimbHelper(sumNeeded,currentSum + 1);
    possibleCombos += countWaysToClimbHelper(sumNeeded,currentSum + 2);
    return possibleCombos;
}
```

**Note:**

- This code could be enhanced further. The whole logic can be implemented inside the `countWaysToClimb()` without using a helper-method. For that, instead of tracking the `currentSum` you need to subtract the number of steps from the `sumNeeded` when the method is called recursively.

Comment: thank you!! this was incredibly helpful, appreciate it.

Comment: Would you happen to know what the time complexity for this algorithm is?

Comment: @SomeoneLearning17 For this solution time complexity will be roughly **O(2 ^ n)**. Because every branch of the execution will spawn **two** new branches.

Comment: @SomeoneLearning17 To improve performance, you can apply so-called memorization technic by adding a `HashMap` which will store all previously computed results. With this enhancement time complexity will be linear, i.e. **O(n)**.